# How to write multiple Boolean expression in one line?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

Can I write the following line in a better way without repeating (c_numbers_list[:2]) phrase over and over?

```
    if c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,1] or c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,2] or c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,3] or 
    c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,4] or c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,5]:
```

Comment: Use `if A in [B,C,D]` like `if c_numbers_list[:2] in [[5,1], [5,2], .....[5,5]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ans = False
for i in range(1,6):
    if c_numbers_list[:2] == [5,i]:
        ans = True
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list has at least 2 elements, you could simply do:

```
if c_numbers_list[0]==5 and c_numbers_list[1] in range(1,6):
    ...
```

If the list could be shorter:

```
if len(c_numbers_list)>1 and c_numbers_list[0]==5 and c_numbers_list[1] in range(1,6):
    ...
```

If you don't want to hard code the comparison values:

```
eligible = [ [5,i] for i in range(1,6) ] # one time setup

if c_numbers_list[:2] in eligible:
    ...
```